# displaying user content as typed in

Tags: javascript, escaping

When a user types in some value in a text box it should be displayed in a **td** as it is.

This is the code I've tried with a **div**,

```
<input type="text" name="userStr" id="userStr" onKeyUp="processValue()"/>
<div id="disp">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function processValue() {

var userval = document.getElementById("userStr").value;
//alert('userval'+userval);
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = userval;
}
```

I enter the value,  &lt&gt &#40 &#41 &#35 &#38 , but it is showing as <> ( ) # & 
instead of the original string (&lt&gt &#40 &#41 &#35 &#38 )

What is the **standard** way to do this.

While I typed **stackoverflow** showed exactly the same, I'll now view the source, but looking for insights from you.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider calling `escape` on `userval`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the `escape()` function is for URL escapes, not HTML.

Comment: @Pointy: you're right. I always forget that initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = userval.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
```

Alternatively, you could set the element text, but you'd have to deal with browser variation.

Comment: was thinking about those lines, I am also considering if the user himself enters reg expression.

Comment: This works for the provided case, am testing for other possible inputs, Thanks

Comment: And how to revert back in the server

Comment: @itsraja what do you mean, "revert back in the server"?  Your overall goal is not really clear here.